# How do I get a widget by it's ID from a PanedWindow?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have a *PanedWindow*.

It's *panes()* it returns a list of *_tkinter.Tcl_Obj*, not a list of widgets in the panes.

How can I get a real widget *add()*'ed to the *PanedWindow* by the ID in *Tcl_Obj.string* ?

(of course, I can subclass *PanedWidget* and keep a list of real widgets).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
pw = tk.PanedWindow(root)
pw.add(tk.Frame(pw))
pw.add(tk.Frame(pw))
panes = pw.panes()

print(type(panes[0]))
print(panes[0].typename)
print(panes[0].string)

# The result is:
# <class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>
# window
# .140650792907720.140650822212800

# how can I get tk.Frame by the ID = .140650792907720.140650822212800 ?
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please share some code that you have tried. If you get errors, please share the full Traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the widget method `nametowidget`:

```
frame = root.nametowidget(panes[0])
```